# NSSlider animation

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsslider

How can I create NSSlider animation when changing float value of it. I was trying:

```
[[mySlider animator] setFloatValue:-5];
```

but that didn't work.. just change the value without animation. So maybe someone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok - so this isn't as quick and pretty as I hoped but it works.
You can't actually use animators and Core Animation on the slider knob - because Core Animation works only on layers and there's no access to the knob values in the slider layer.

So we have to resort instead to manually animating slider value.
Since we're doing this on a Mac - you can use [NSAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which isn't available on iOS).

What NSAnimation does is simple - it provide an timing/interpolation mechanism to allow YOU to animate (as opposed to Core Animation which also connects to the views and handles the changes to them).

To use NSAnimation - you most commonly would subclass it and override `setCurrentProgress:` 
 and put your logic in there.

Here's how I implemented this - I created a new NSAnimation subclass called `NSAnimationForSlider`

NSAnimationForSlider.h :

```
@interface NSAnimationForSlider : NSAnimation  
{  
    NSSlider *delegateSlider;  
    float animateToValue;    
    double max;   
    double min;  
    float initValue;  
}  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSlider *delegateSlider;  
@property (nonatomic, assign) float animateToValue;    
@end
```

NSAnimationForSlider.m :

```
#import "NSAnimationForSlider.h"

@implementation NSAnimationForSlider
@synthesize delegateSlider;
@synthesize animateToValue;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [delegateSlider release], delegateSlider = nil;
}

-(void)startAnimation
{
    //Setup initial values for every animation
    initValue = [delegateSlider floatValue];
    if (animateToValue >= initValue) {
        min = initValue;
        max = animateToValue;
    } else  {
        min = animateToValue;
        max = initValue;
    }

    [super startAnimation];
}


- (void)setCurrentProgress:(NSAnimationProgress)progress
{
    [super setCurrentProgress:progress];

    double newValue;
    if (animateToValue >= initValue) {
        newValue = min + (max - min) * progress;        
    } else  {
        newValue = max - (max - min) * progress;
    }

    [delegateSlider setDoubleValue:newValue];
}

@end
```

To use it - you simply create a new NSAnimationForSlider, give it the slider you are working on as a delegate and before each animation you set it's animateToValue and then just start the animation.

For example:

```
slider = [[NSSlider alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(50, 150, 400, 25)];
[slider setMaxValue:200];
[slider setMinValue:50];
[slider setDoubleValue:50];

[[window contentView] addSubview:slider];

NSAnimationForSlider *sliderAnimation = [[NSAnimationForSlider alloc] initWithDuration:2.0 animationCurve:NSAnimationEaseIn];
[sliderAnimation setAnimationBlockingMode:NSAnimationNonblocking];
[sliderAnimation setDelegateSlider:slider];
[sliderAnimation setAnimateToValue:150];

[sliderAnimation startAnimation];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe you can say more accurate how to do this?  because I didn't understand exactly what do you mean. What do you mean saying basic animation? "animator" I think is basic animation.

Comment: I'll be at my desktop soon and try to write it up in code for you

Comment: Right, we are talking about Mac.

Comment: wow! It's not so easy! THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY MUCH for your help!!! I will go to test and use Your code! Wow again, Thank You very much!!!

Comment: Pleasure is mine - if you find problems or improvements - post 'em back here. Good luck!

Comment: Don't be confused by sliderDelegate. That is NOT the actual delegate and will not receive NSAnimationDelegate callbacks, you still want to set some controller or your app delegate to the delegate and implement NSAnimationDelegate methods there to get callbacks or handle animation progress or completion.

Answer (score 4):

Your method works, but there's something much simpler.

You **can** use the animator proxy, you just need to tell it how to animate it.
To do this, you need to implement the `defaultAnimationForKey:` method from the `NSAnimatablePropertyContainer` protocol.

---

Here's a simple subclass of `NSSlider` that does this:

```
#import "NSAnimatableSlider.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation NSAnimatableSlider

+ (id)defaultAnimationForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"doubleValue"]) {
        return [CABasicAnimation animation];
    } else {
        return [super defaultAnimationForKey:key];
    }
}

@end
```

---

Now you can simply use the animator proxy:

```
[self.slider.animator setDoubleValue:100.0];
```

---

Make sure to link the `QuartzCore` framework.

Comment: According to [this example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AnimatedSlider/Listings/AnimatedSlider_NSSliderExtensions_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000378-AnimatedSlider_NSSliderExtensions_m-DontLinkElementID_6), you can also enable this with a class extension. But subclassing is less likely to interfere with other code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift version of [IluTov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573193/7090917), setting a `floatValue` with some animation config:

```
override class func defaultAnimation(forKey key: NSAnimatablePropertyKey) -> Any? {
    if key == "floatValue" {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation()
        animation.timingFunction = .init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        animation.duration = 0.2
        
        return animation
    } else {
        return super.defaultAnimation(forKey: key)
    }
}
```